# Passing react component up the tree

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs

In my application i have a need to display pop-up dialogs. Those dialogs need to be located near the top of DOM tree to make absolute positioning work properly. Each page can have different dialog.

I have an app structure like this

```
var Dialog = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div> Hello world! </div>
    }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        this.props.onDialogChange(<Dialog />)
    },
    render: function() {
    return (
      <div onClick = {this.handleClick}>
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
 }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {dialog: null};
  }, 
  handleDialogChange: function(dialog) {
    this.setState({dialog: dialog});
  },
  render: function {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dialog}
        <Page onDialogChange = {this.handleDialogChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Everything works, but i have a warning in the console

```
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ
```

Am i doing it wrong and should i refactor my app structure?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the problem of how React passes context based on the rendering tree. Take a look at how [React Portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by passing the function that will create the component, instead of component itself. No warning anymore. The example would look like:

```
var Dialog = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div> {this.props.text} </div>
    }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        this.props.onDialogChange(React.createElement.bind(null, Dialog, {text: 'hello world!'}))
    },
    render: function() {
    return (
      <div onClick = {this.handleClick}>
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
 }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {dialogCreator: null};
  }, 
  handleDialogChange: function(dialogCreator) {
    this.setState({dialogCreator: dialogCreator});
  },
  render: function {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.dialogCreator ? this.state.dialogCreator() : null }
        <Page onDialogChange = {this.handleDialogChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning means : your Page component(owner-based) is owning Dialog component (owner-based is where the component is rendered). and your App component (parent-based) is the parent of Dialog.

To solve the problem, you should pass `<Dialog/>` in `<handleDialogChange>` of the App component so the owner-based and parent-based become the same. In `<Page>`, you just call a handler to trigger the `<handleDiaLogChange>`